# How can I change drives using python os?

Tags: python, windows, chdir

I'm trying to change the current directory from `C:` to `Y:`
I tried:

```
import os
os.chdir('Y:')
```

but I keep getting an error saying that it can't locate the drive.
Essentially I'm looking for the equivalent of the

```
cd /d
```

command in cmd.

Comment: You realize that "change the current directory from C: to Y:" doesn't actually mean anything in Windows? There's a current default drive, and a separate current directory for each drive. So, you can change the current drive to Y:, or you can change the current drive to Y: and change the directory on that to \, but those are different operations. (At the C API level it's _chdrive(25) vs. _chdir("Y:\\"), and it's probably similar in Python, except that chdrive probably doesn't exist in os and you have to go to msvcrt, or even ctypes the actual MSVCRT DLL.)

Comment: I realized my connection to Y: had been disrupted somehow, but once I sorted that out chdir('Y:') worked fine.
Thanks for the help in any case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure `Y:` really is a valid drive letter?

Try `os.chdir('C:')` and make sure that works. (It works for me.)

Comment: I have a Y: drive and I have been able to access it using "cd /d Y:"

Comment: @aensm: Even if `os.chdir('Y:')` worked, it doesn't do the same thing as a "cd /d Y:" does. See @abarnert's comment.

Comment: my guess is that Y: in not a drive, while Y:\ is.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a mapped network drive, your best bet is to use the UNC path instead of the mapped path. Also, try to use a raw `r` string modifier when using paths under windows, if you're not using `os.path.join`.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'\\server\path') 
print os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing (Drive:path\to\folder) try switching the slashes to (Drive:path/to/folder)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is asking to change drives not folders.